# How to run a local program with user input in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to get user input from a web page written in Perl and send it to a local program (blastp), then display the results.

This is what I have right now:

```
(input code)

print $q->p, "Your database: $bd",
$q->p, "Your protein is: $prot",
$q->p, "Executing...";

print $q->p, system("blastp","-db $bd","-query $prot","-out results.out");
```

Now, I've done a little research, but I can't quite grasp how you're supposed to do things like this in Perl. I've tried opening a file, writing to it, and sending it over to blastp as an input, but I was unsuccessful.

For reference, this line produces a successful output file:

```
 kold@sazabi ~/BLAST/pataa $ blastp -db pataa -query ../teste.fs -out results.out
```

I may need to force the bd to load from an absolute path, but that shouldn't be difficult.

edit: Yeah, the DBs have an environmental variable, that's fixed. Ok, all I need is to get the input into a file, pass it to the command, and then print the output file to the CGI page.

edit2: for clarification:

I am receiving user input in $prot, I want to pass it over to blastp in -query, have the program blastp execute, and then print out to the user the results.out file (or just have a link to it, since blastp can output in HTML)

EDIT:

All right, fixed everything I needed to fix. The big problem was me not seeing what was going wrong: I had to install Tiny:Capture and print out stderr, which was when I realized the environmental variable wasn't getting set correctly, so BLAST wasn't finding my databases. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: i dont understan what you want, explain more

Comment: Added some more detail.

Comment: Is $prot going to contain the NAME of the file, or contents?

Comment: Right now, I was planning on $prot to receive FASTA text, namely something that looks like this:

    >gi|218093591|emb|CAT70956.1| unnamed protein product [Thermococcus kodakarensis KOD1] MKVLVAAPLHEKAIEVLKNAGFEVVYEEYPDEDRLVELVKDVDAIIVRSKPKVTRKVIEAAPKLKVIGRA GVGLDNIDLKAAEERGIKVVNSPGASSRSVAELAIGLIFAVARKIAFADRKMREGVWAKKQCMGIELEGK TIGVVGFGRIGYQVAKIANALGMKVLFYDPYPNEERAKEVGGKFADLETLLKESDVVTLHVPLVDATYHL INEERLKLMKPTAILINAARGAVVDTDALVKALQEGWIAGAGLDVFEEEPLPADHPLTKLDNVVLTPHIG ASTVEAQMRAGVEVAEKIVEALKG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write `$prot` to the file. Assuming you need to do it as-is without processing the text to split it or something:

   - For a fixed file name (may be problematic):

     ```
     use File::Slurp;
     write_file("../teste.fs", $prot, "\n") or print_error_to_web(); 
           # Implement the latter to print error in nice HTML format
     ```
   - For a temp file (better):

     ```
     my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile( $template, DIR => "..", CLEANUP => 1);
     # You can also create temp directory which is even better, via tempdir()
     print $fh "$prot\n";
     close $fh;
     ```
2. Step 2: Run your command as you indicated:

   ```
   my $rc = system("$BLASTP_PATH/blastp", "-db", "pataa"
                   ,"-query", "../teste.fs", "-out", "results.out");
   # Process $rc for errors
   # Use qx[] instead of system() if you want to capture 
   #      standard output of the command
   ```
3. Step 3: Read the output file in:

   ```
   use File::Slurp;
   my $out_file_text = read_file("results.out");
   ```
4. Send back to web server

   ```
   print $q->p, $out_file_text;
   ```

The above code has multiple issues (e.g. you need better file/directory paths, more error handling etc...) but should start you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot. There's still a problem, though: apparently I need to preserve the newlines and write_file isn't doing it correctly. My input file, and the test print I do of $prot, show a newline after the first bit, like the comment I made up there, but the file produced by write_file has everything in one line, making BLAST unable to recognize it.

Comment: @JoséMaia - that's exactly why I said "Assuming you need to do it as-is without processing the text to split it or something". If you need to know how to do that, look into `split`

Comment: Ok, having fixed the problems, the code is now producing a correct input.fs file, as well as a correct (blastp -db pataa -query input.fs -out results.out) query. However, the results.out file is empty, despite the query working if I execute it manually in the terminal. Is there a place I should be looking at for the logs to figure out what happened?

Comment: Don't think it's a permissions problem either, seeing as if I su into www-data and execute the code, it works.